# mouse hover, make only the text bold , the underline should be normal

Tags: html, css

simple html and css.

code:

```
   <div class="link_my"> <a href="a.php">my link</a></div>
```

css:

```
.link_my a:hover{

font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:underline;

}
```

on mouse hover, the text font becomes bold along with the ubderline. But I want the underline to be normal (not bold).

How to do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work for you Istiaque.
JS FIDDLE LINK : http://jsfiddle.net/39TtM/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link">
    <span>
        my link
    </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link span{
    color:blue;
    font-size:30px;
}

.link:hover span{
    font-weight:bold;
}

.link:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use border-bottom instead

```
.link_my a:hover{

font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;

}
```

Thanks
John

Comment: To improve on the answer from david id suggest adding a transparent border on the item and change the color on hover http://jsfiddle.net/VA23f/

Comment: why to add transparent border ?

Comment: Sorry I was sure that one of the browsers would make the content jump if you didn't set a transparent border, however i think i am wrong.

Comment: @JohnC You are not wrong. The content may not "jump" visibly but the browser will have to repaint everything each time a link will be hovered which is a graphic intensive task. For performance having a transparent border is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

The underline is part of the text, they're *not* distinct elements/parts.

One way around this is to use `border` rather than an underline:

```
.link_my a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.link_my a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ay3EV/).

Comment: border and underline - do those occupy exactly the same position ?

Comment: No; an `underline` appears under the text, but 'above' (at the upper edge) of the leading space (or dropping-space?) below the text; whereas a border is at the bottom edge of the element. They're *similar*, but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using **line-height** (maybe display:block too), Aditya's solution might be preferable > else (when using border-bottom) the underline would appear under the block-element instead of under the text as desired.

Comment: Please clarify what  means beyond David's answer .

Comment: to clarify and go beyond (you're right, ahmed) > to get the visual output wanted here, it's necessary in both cases(!) to add an extra element, either to keep the border-bottom directly under the text (and not under the visible element, that contains it) or to separate the underline-style from the bold style. >>> so aditya's solution might be better, because it's closer to the design logic

Comment: why is this an answer, not a comment ?